# In sbt, how to make a setting value scoped by a task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using sbt 0.13.16 and I'm trying to have a the setting `version` having a different value depending of the task using it. I'm trying to add the postfix `-SNAPSHOT` with `publishLocal`

I tried to scope the value

```
version := appVersion
version in publishLocal :=  appVersion + "-SNAPSHOT"
```

or even to create a new config (but I would prefer a solution not involving a new configuration)

```
val Dev = config("dev") extend Compile
version := appVersion
version in Dev := appVersion + "-SNAPSHOT"
```

In the second case, typing `dev:version` in the sbt repl does output a version correctly postfixed but `dev:publishLocal` still create artifacts that are not postfixed.